# Google maps registered URL scheme in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

Is there Google maps application launch link which is registered as URL scheme in iPhone?
I know i can launch Google maps using http://maps.google.com  ...
But this needs internet connection. I'm looking for a launch link which does not require internet connection like Waze (waze://?ll ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps app can be launched from the maps URL already:
 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

This way, if Google Maps is not installed then the user will be redirected to a web site and thereby provide a graceful degradation of service.

Note that in iOS6 the new maps application means that some of the above will be different - check the iOS6 docs if you have a developer account, or wait until its public information.

The problem of whether or not you need an internet connection is different however.  If the map section is cached, then Google Maps won't necessarily need an internet connection - but that's in no way guaranteed, and nothing you can do about launching the app is going to change that.

You could launch Waze (if it's installed) - check out their API documentation for details how to do this:
 http://world.waze.com/dev/documentation/

Comment: It really launched maps app. But it still throwed an alert that it can't navigate because it has no internet connection. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, if you need navigation then Maps is the wrong application for you as it will always need a net connection.  Check out the Waze URL above and also http://gps.motionx.com/iphone/partnerapps/ - maybe some other APIs out there for apps like TomTom?  You could then try each URL in turn (`(BOOL) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:..]`) and fall back to Maps as a last resort - then if your user has offline navigation installed they'll get it.